# Erro ao tentar conectar com o servidor FTP Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estou tentando me conectar com o servidor externo FTP com a lib 3.6 atual do apache ftp client utilizando o Android Studio, a versão do meu Android é 4.3 até o atual 9.

No meu Manifest tenho:

Utilizo o *FTPClient* com o `commons-net-3.6.jar` Importada na Lib do projeto.

Na minha classe de conexão tenho.

Método Dir de diretório:

```
public FTPFile[] Dir(String Diretorio) {
        try {
            FTPFile[] ftpFiles = mFtp.listFiles(Diretorio);
            return ftpFiles;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Erro: não foi possível listar os arquivos e pastas do diretório " + Diretorio + ". " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

O método Conectar:

```
public boolean Conectar(String Host, String Usuario, String Senha, int Porta) {
        try {
            mFtp = new FTPClient();
            mFtp.connect(Host, Porta);

            if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(mFtp.getReplyCode())) {

                boolean status = mFtp.login(Usuario, Senha);
                mFtp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                mFtp.enterLocalPassiveMode();

                return status;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Erro: não foi possível conectar: " + Host);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

E no `fragment` tenho os métodos.

```
public void ListarArquivosdoFTP() {
        classe_FTP ClienteFTP = new classe_FTP();
        ClienteFTP.Conectar("ftp.meuhost.com.br", "meu user", "minha senha", 21);
        FTPFile[] arquivos = ClienteFTP.Dir("/httpdocs/expresso1002/recibo/112019");
        if (arquivos != null) {
            int length = arquivos.length;
            for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
                FTPFile f = arquivos[i];
                if (f.isFile()) {
                    ArquivosFTP.add(f.getName());
                }
            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, ArquivosFTP);
            SpnListarArquivosFTP.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }
    }
```

Estou chamando assim no `OnCreateView`:

```
ListarArquivosdoFTP();
```

E no LogCat mostra esse erro quando abro o `fragment`:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:13292)
        at android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:2058)
        at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.callFromPackage(SettingsProvider.java:615)
        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:279)
        at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:273)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
12-16 14:30:39.461 11615-11615/expresso.escala1002 E/classeFTP: Erro: não foi possível conectar: ftp.meuhost.com.br
12-16 14:30:39.461 11615-11615/expresso.escala1002 E/classeFTP: Erro: não foi possível listar os arquivos e pastas do diretório /httpdocs/expresso1002/recibo/112019. Connection is not open
```

Tenho outro método que lista um diretório do celular e mostra todos os itens em um `Spinner` e funciona perfeitamente, estou querendo fazer o mesmo com esse, tenho que acessar a pasta indicada no FTP e listar todos os itens. 
Como resolver esse erro ao tentar conectar?

Answer (score -1):

Consegui resolve esse problema.

Alterei o método `ListarArquivosdoFTP()` adicionando thread:

```
public void ListarArquivosdoFTP() {

        new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                try{
                    classe_FTP ClienteFTP = new classe_FTP();
                    ClienteFTP.Conectar("ftp.meuhost.com.br", "usuario", "senha", 21);
                    FTPFile[] arquivos = ClienteFTP.Dir("/caminho");
                    if (arquivos != null) {
                        int length = arquivos.length;
                        for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
                            FTPFile f = arquivos[i];
                            if (f.isFile()) {
                                ArquivosFTP.add(f.getName());
                            }
                        }

                        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, ArquivosFTP);
                        SpnListarArquivosFTP.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                    }
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
```